# How to emit to a specific socket with a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Hi I want to emit to a specific socket which I stored in a variable :

```
 socket.on('register', () => {
     clintToEmitTo = socket.id;
     console.log('clint To Emit To Socket ID ', clintToEmitTo);
 });
```

I know that to send to a specific socket I need to do the following :

```
 socket.to(clintToEmitTo).emit('getName', (response) => {
    console.log(response);
 });
```

However, I want to be able to use a callback or acknowledgement , this is what I get :

> (node:1956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Callbacks are not supported when
>   broadcasting (node:1956) [DEP0018]

note that: the emit event can be triggered by another client event which is why I didn't add a callback on the registered event

Comment: `emit` expects some object as second param, you are passing a `function`, can be that the problem? try move the function callback as 3rd param.

Comment: it doesn't make a difference, you still get the same error. what do you mean by (move the function callback as 3rd param)

Comment: `socket.to(clintToEmitTo).emit('getName', '', (response) => {
   console.log(response);
});`

Comment: yah that comes out with the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just send something? :

```
  socket.to(clintToEmitTo).emit('getName', "something");
```

Comment: it doesn't make a difference, you still get the same error if you have the callback. socket.to(clintToEmitTo).emit('getName', "something") or socket.to(clintToEmitTo).emit('getName') will work fine , but you wont be able to get perfom a callback